# Jquery tablesorter text extraction

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Jquery tablesorter

I am using Jquery tablesorter 2.0 and i need to sort table with the column which has input and select and break tag.

I tried many ways of using text extraction. But i am not getting the desired result.It considers the content as text.

This is my td and want to sort the input text data.

```
<td>
    <input type=text maxlength=2 size=1 value="10"><br>
    <select >
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="S"> s</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Pls. help.

Comment: Please provide some HTML, or even better a demo of your table.

Answer (score 0):

I think a parser would be a better idea.

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "input",
    is: function(s, table, cell){
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell) {
        return $(cell).find('input').val() || s;
    },
    type: "text"
});
```

then initialize the table like this:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    headers: {
        // 0 is the index of the first column (zero-based)
        0: { sorter: 'input' }
    }
});
```

Note: If you are using tablesorter v2.0.5, then the above parser will work just fine, but if you use the "updateCell" method, it won't work.